# Resolve bindings for new created types?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am developing an Eclipse plug-in to refactor Java source code with JDT. I create some new classes, but experienced problems with the resolving of these new types. Therefore is my question: is it possible to resolve new created types without reparsing them?

```java
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setSource(existingCompilationUnit);

CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);

AST ast = unit.getAST();

// create a new type
TypeDeclaration newCreatedType = ast.newTypeDeclaration();
// fill type declaration with methods, fields, etc.
// ...

// create new compilation unit for the new type
CompilationUnit newCreatedCompilationUnit = ast.newCompilationUnit();
newCreatedCompilationUnit.types().add(newCreatedType);

newCreatedType.resolveBinding(); // returns null
```

It is of course possible to reparse it, but then it is contained within another AST, which causes problems when I try to rewrite elements of the AST:

```java
parser.setSource(newCreatedCompilationUnit);
CompilationUnit newParsedCompilationUnit = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
TypeDeclaration newParsedType = (TypeDeclaration)newParsedCompilationUnit.types().get(0);
newParsedType.resolveBinding() // returns a correct binding, but newParsedType.getAST() != ast
```

Then I tried to copy the new type to the old AST, which corrects the AST, but the binding informations are lost again:

```java
CompilationUnit copiedCompilationUnit = (CompilationUnit) newUnit.copySubtree(ast, newParsedCompilationUnit);
// (copiedCompilationUnit.getAST() == ast) is true
TypeDeclaration copiedType = (TypeDeclaration)copiedCompilationUnit.types().get(0);
copiedType.resolveBinding() // returns null
```

By now I must decide between no binding or the wrong AST and I cannot find a solution to that.

Comment: Have you tried to save and reparse both the new and the changed compilation units?